# sending custom password reset form

Tags: python, django

I want to reset password in django app by visiting a certain url and passing e-mail by POST method. That's because I want to use it in an android app, which will have its own form. So, I thought I could create a custom password reset form and then save it, but it doesn work.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

class Custom_password_reset_form(PasswordResetForm):
    def __init__(self, email, **kwargs):
        super(Custom_password_reset_form, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.email = forms.EmailField(initial=email, max_length=254)


def mobile_password_reset(request):
    """Sends mail with password reset link."""
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    my_form = Custom_password_reset_form(email)

    if my_form.is_valid():
        print 'valid'
        my_form.save()
    else:
        print 'not valid'
        print my_form._errors
    return render(...)
```

Validation always fails, giving empty `my_form._errors` list. What am I missing here? Or maybe there is some better way to do this?

**Correct code:**

The custom class is unnecessary, and should be removed. The password resetting method should look like this:

```
def mobile_password_reset(request):
    """Sends mail with password reset link."""
    my_form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST)
    if my_form.is_valid():
        my_form.save()
        return JsonResponse({'success': True})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'success': False})
```

It's important to note, that without `django.contrib.sites` app added to settings, `my_form.save()` will not work. It could be also fixed by adding this argument: `my_form.save(request=request)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form [needs to be bound to data to be valid](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms). You are passing the email argument but no `data`, so the form will always be unbound. For unbound forms, `is_valid()` returns `False`, but there are no errors.

I don't understand what your custom form is required for. If the `email` is in `request.POST`, why not just pass `request.POST` to the regular `PasswordRestForm`?

```
my_form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding django's auth module.
Add following urls in your urls.py

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', PasswordReset.as_view(is_admin_site=True),
    {'is_admin_site': 'True'}),
```

After this, add following views

```
class PasswordReset(RedirectView):
is_admin_site = False
template_name = 'forget_password.html'
email_template_name = 'password_reset_email.html'
subject_template_name = 'password_reset_subject.html'
token_generator = default_token_generator
post_reset_redirect = None
from_email = None,
current_app = None,
extra_context = None

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    form = YourCustomPasswordResetForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    if self.extra_context is not None:
        context.update(self.extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, self.template_name, context,
                            current_app=self.current_app)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = YourCustomPasswordResetForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if self.from_email is not None:
            from_email = 'From Email'
        opts = {
            'use_https': request.is_secure(),
            'token_generator': self.token_generator,
            'from_email': self.from_email,
            'email_template_name': self.email_template_name,
            'subject_template_name': self.subject_template_name,
            'request': request,
        }
        if self.is_admin_site:
            opts = dict(opts, domain_override=request.get_host())
        form.save(**opts)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.post_reset_redirect)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    if self.extra_context is not None:
        context.update(self.extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, self.template_name, context,
                            current_app=self.current_app)
```

In you forms, add you form and add folloing save method in it.

```
def save(self, domain_override=None,
         subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
         email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
         use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator,
         from_email=None, request=None):
    """
    Generates a one-use only link for resetting password and sends to the
    user.
    """
    from_email = 'From Email'
    from django.core.mail import send_mail

    user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
    if not domain_override:
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        site_name = current_site.name
        domain = current_site.domain
    else:
        site_name = domain = domain_override
        c = {
            'email': user.email,
            'domain': domain,
            'site_name': site_name,
            'uid': int_to_base36(user.id),
            'user': user,
            'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
            'protocol': use_https and 'https' or 'http',
        }
    subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, c)
    # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
    subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
    email = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
    send_mail(subject, email, from_email, [user.email])
```

When you will submit that form, user will get email with a link containing a token. That link can only used once.

Comment: I haven't tested your answer, but it seems to be too heavy for my issue.